# GetModuleFilename returns wrong folder name running through VBScript

Tags: c++, vbscript

I'm creating an object for COM

```vb
Set FM_L = CreateObject("FMInterface.FMDebug")
```

in VBScript. In `Fmdebug` I have a method that calls `GetModuleFilename` (C++ method). It returns the wrong folder path (`C:\Windows\System32`).

If I'm running this same DLL from a C# application I'm getting the correct path. Only in VBScript I'm getting a wrong folder path.

Code:

```cpp
static string ExePath() {
  char buffer[MAX_PATH];
  GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
  string::size_type pos = string( buffer ).find_last_of( "\\/" );
  return string( buffer ).substr( 0, pos);
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Try using GetModuleHandle before calling GetModuleFileName and use that handle as a parameter in GetModuleFileName.

Comment: i thought wscript.exe folder path is returning .. bcoz vb script is running with the help of same. so without changing dll(its not in my hand) any change the script  to get right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rauls Thanks for saying modulehandle.
With Modulehandle it solved .. 
source - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16598/Get-Your-DLL-s-Path-Name